# Creating a torch tensor from a generator

Tags: pytorch

I attempt to construct a tensor from a generator as follows:

```
>>> torch.tensor(i**2 for i in range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of generator
```

Currently I just do:

```
>>> torch.tensor([i**2 for i in range(10)])
tensor([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```

Is there a way to avoid needing this intermediate list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @blue-phoenox already points out, it is preferred to use the built-in PyTorch functions to create the tensor directly. But if you have to deal with generator, it can be advisable to use numpy as a intermediate stage. Since PyTorch avoid to copy the numpy array, it should be quite performat (compared to the simple list comprehension)

```
>>> import torch
>>> import numpy as np
>>> torch.from_numpy(np.fromiter((i**2 for i in range(10)), int))
tensor([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution! I would hope there would be a better way that doesn't rely on numpy as an intermediary, but this is basically what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you want to use a generator. The list doesn't really make a difference here.

The question is: Do you want to create your data in **Python** first and *move* it then to **PyTorch** (slower in most cases) **or** do you want to create it *directly* in **PyTorch**.
*(A generator would always create the data in Python first)*

So if you want to *load data* the story is different, but if you want to *generate data* I see no reason why you shouldn't do so in *PyTorch directly*.

---

If you want to directly create your list in PyTorch for your example you can do so using `arange` and `pow`:

```
torch.arange(10).pow(2)
```

Output:

```
tensor([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```

---

`torch.arange(10)` works the same way like `range` in python, so it's exactly as versatile `range`. Then `pow(2)` just takes your tensor to the 2nd power.

But you can also do all other sorts of computation instead of `pow` once you created your tensor using `arange`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It provides a good workaround, but the core of my question is really: can I use python generators (with the great syntax python provides for them) to produce a torch tensor. My original motivating example was more along the lines of:
```
>>>torch.tensor(my_distribution.sample() for _ in range(10))
```